# First CSOM Program failes

Tags: csom

Today I copied the following code from my book to test my first SharePoint-CSOM application, but I cannot get it to work properly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace csom
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://serverone");
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
            FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo loginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo
            {
                LoginName = "myusername@domain.com",
                Password = "mypassword"
            };
            ctx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = loginInfo;

            Site site = ctx.Site;
            ctx.Load(site);
            Web web = site.RootWeb;
            ctx.Load(web);
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project types");
            ctx.Load(list);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown and I really cannot find the reason for this. I enabled FormAuthentication in the Central Administration and in IIS for this Website so this cant be the problem...

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Services.dll
>
> Additional information: Server was unable to process request. ---> The
>   server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. 
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

Any idea what I could still try?
Of course the values for servers and passwords are changed in this post :)

I googled how to turn on this attribute, and I figured that I have to change my web.config as follows:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" behaviorConfiguration="debug" />
    </services> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

However, this does not work. How can I turn on includeExceptionDetailInFaults in this case?

Thanks

Comment: THe code seems fine to me. Do you have access to server-side logs? Or maybe turn on `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults`

Comment: -------------------------------------------------

Comment: How about server logs? It's hard to advise on generic "internal error" failure, we'll need details

Comment: Do you mean the logs in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS". There I can find exactly the same information like Visual Studio gives me, but no more. Is there another server log I can look in?

Comment: Is SharePoint configured to use Forms Authentication? If not you are most likely passing the wrong type of credential.

Comment: Yes, I went to Central Administration, Web applications and I configured my web application for Forms Authentication. I also restarted IIS... I actually almost gave up now... maybe I just can not use FA...

Comment: Can you log into the site through the browser using Forms Auth?

Answer (score 1):

try an alternate method to login as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;
using System.Net;


namespace Study
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://yourSiteUrl");
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in "yourPassword".ToCharArray())
                passWord.AppendChar(c);

            clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourLoginName", passWord, "yourSharePointDomain");

            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            List testList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("yourListTitle");
            clientContext.Load(testList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
}
```